# Pass "type" of struct as an argument in Swift?

Tags: swift

Is it possible to pass the "type" of a struct as an argument? Use case below (syntax doesn't work):

```
// Declarations.
public protocol Event {}

public enum AwesomeEvents {
  public enum Notifications {
    public struct NotificationReceived : Event {
      ...
    }
  }
}

// Is it possible to do something like this?
func testNotifications {
  ...
  doSomethingAndCheckEventType(correctEventType: AwesomeEvents.Notifications.NotificationReceived.Type)
}

func doSomethingAndCheckEventType<T: Event>(correctEventType: T) {
  ...
  XCTestAssertTrue(someEvent is correctEventType)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [the == operator for metatypes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541152).

```swift
func testNotifications() {
  doSomethingAndCheckEventType(correctEventType: AwesomeEvents.Notifications.NotificationReceived.self)
}

func doSomethingAndCheckEventType<CorrectEvent: Event>(correctEventType: CorrectEvent.Type) {
  let someEvent = AwesomeEvents.Notifications.NotificationReceived()
  XCTAssert(type(of: someEvent) == correctEventType)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
func testNotifications {
  ...
  doSomethingAndCheckEventType(correctEventType: AwesomeEvents.Notifications.NotificationReceived.self)
}

func doSomethingAndCheckEventType<T: Event>(correctEventType: T.Type) {
  ...
  XCTestAssertTrue(someEvent is T)
}
```